# Macbook pro sometimes left clicks are not registered

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, click

Hi I have a macbook pro 15", primo 2011.

It runs perfect with Mavericks. However recently it has started to get a strange bug from time to time. Some times left clicks on the pad is not working. It happens randomly while I work. It's often happening when I e.g. want to close a window in finder or change/close a tab in safari.

The issue shows like this: When I for an example hover over the "X" and clicks to close the window, nothing happens. I can try 10 times but nothing works. Right clicking though always seems to work. I have noticed that if I move the pointer a little around (maybe clicking elsewhere) and then back on the "X" again, then it always works fine again.

The issue comes and goes, and I cannot find any pattern, except that it's happening for every 20. left click I'm doing, that the computer seems to not register it.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well, and I just realized that the problem might be because I swapped the hdd drive with other macbook and the when I installed osx the hdd it was in a different macbook, so probably after a reinstall would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an external usb mouse and if the left click works then you know that it is the Macbook Pro's trackpad that is the issue , if the Trackpad is the issue then I would recommend talking to Apple about a repair.

Comment: It's not the trackpad. It also happens with an external mouse and using both the trackpads click and touch functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue from day one(!) in my retina macbook pro (mid 2012). I call few times apple but I didn't get any solution. I tried everything. As you say it's difficult to find a pattern. This problem solved when I clean install the OS X :/ I know that is not the ideal solution you want but it's a solution that works.